# How to prove $\left(\frac{e^n-1}{n}\right)^{2n+1} \leq \frac{(e-1)(e^2-1)...(e^{2n}-1)}{(2n)!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, convexity-inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$\left(\frac{e^n-1}{n}\right)^{2n+1} \leq \frac{(e-1)(e^2-1)...(e^{2n}-1)}{(2n)!}$$

For the base case $n=1$

$$0 \leq e-1$$

Lets assume the inequality holds for $n$, then I have to prove that:

$$\left(\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)^{2(n+1)+1} \leq \frac{(e-1)(e^2-1)...(e^{2(n+1)}-1)}{(2(n+1))!}$$

Lets start with the RHS:

$$\frac{(e-1)(e^2-1)...(e^{2(n+1)}-1)}{(2(n+1))!}=\frac{(e-1)(e^2-1)...(e^{2n}-1)}{(2n)!} \frac{(e^{2n+1}-1)(e^{2n+2}-1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} $$

Now the LHS:

$$\left(\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)^{2(n+1)+1}=\left(\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{e^{n}e-1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{e^{n}e-1}{n+1}\right)^{2}$$

Well thats how far I generally got.

Is there a good way to rewrite the LHS, to solve this? Or is this approach wrong in general?

Looking at this inequality I also tried to use the convexity of $exp$ as an approach but this didn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convexity, assuming $\frac{e^x-1}x=1$ at $x=0$, we have

$$\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\log\left(\frac{e^k-1}k\right)\ge  \log\left(\frac{e^{\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k}-1}{\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k}\right)=\log\left(\frac{e^n-1}n\right)$$

which implies

$$\prod_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{e^k-1}k \ge \left(\frac{e^n-1}n\right)^{2n+1}$$

---

For the convexity we need to show that

$$f(x)=\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right) \implies f''(x)=\frac{e^{2x}+1-e^x(x^2+2)}{x^2(e^x-1)^2}\ge 0$$

which is not much difficult using derivatives to study the sign for numerator.

Comment: Your first inequality is incorrect, because $\log$ is not a convex function (it is in fact concave). However, the composition $\log\circ f$ is a convex function. So, you need to compute the 2nd derivative of the composition only.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes indeed I've indicated that, in the last part of the answer, I'm claiming that $g(x)=\log(f(x))$ is convex.

Comment: Then remove the first inequality, it's confusing otherwise.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Ah ok, of course! I get your point. I fix it

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Revised now! Let me know if in this form it works fine! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for fixing, +1!

Comment: Thanks again for your support! Bye